# Newbie stuck with fields_for and nested attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for, fields-for

Rails newbie here. I'm stuck on fields_for in Rails, and would be eternally grateful for anyone's help.

- In Events#new, why am I getting NoMethodError? 
  Error message says undefined method `name'
- In Events, why am I getting NameError?
  Error message says undefined local variable or method 'event'.

I am trying to create and view a form where each event has 2 fields for each friend.

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
 <div class="field">
Date: <%= f.text_field :date %></br>
Friends: <%= f.fields_for :friends do |friends_fields| %>
  <%= friends_fields.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

index.html.erb:

```
<tbody>
<% @events.each do |event_form| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= event_form.date %></td>
    <td><%= event_form.friends.each do |friend| %>
      <%= friend.name %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', event %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', event, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

event.rb:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :friends
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :friends, allow_destroy: true
end
```

friend.rb:

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :event
end
```

events_controller.rb:

```
def new
    @event = Event.new
    2.times { @event.friends.build }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Event is not defined because events iterator uses event_form instead of event variable name in each iteration. Try changing to this:

```
<tbody>
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= event.date %></td>
    <td><%= event.friends.each do |friend| %>
      <%= friend.name %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', event %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', event, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That's fixed the issue in index.html.erb, but Events#new is still returning me 'NoMethodError', undefined method 'name'. 

If I change    :name      to      :event       in _form.html.erb to fix the error, then nothing shows up in the database friends frields when I create a new form... Sorry if I'm being unclear :(

Comment: Have you got a name column at friends table? Could you post the whole exception trace?

Comment: I don't have a name column. I tried replacing 'name' with 'event', and that fixes the issue, but I still can't get any values to show up in the friends fields

undefined method `name' for #<Friend:0x007faec170ef28>

Comment: friends table should have a name column to get it working. <%= friends_fields.text_field :name %> sends name method to friends model.  Rails creates accessors for each column in your table, thats why Rails is complaining about a name method missing in Friend. More or less it is what Rails does: @event.friends[n].name